# Why didn't Theodore Bikel appear again as Worf's foster father?

Tags: casting, star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

In the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode "Family", actor [Theodore Bikel](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000942) appeared as Worf's foster father, and actress Georgia Brown appeared as Worf's foster mother.  Later in the series, in the episode "New Ground", Brown reprised her role, yet Bikel did not appear.

**Why did Bikel not appear again in this role?**  Was he unavailable (and for what)?  Not interested in the role?  Asked for too much money (he *had* been the president of Actors' Equity)?  Became [two feet tall at four o'clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_O%27Clock_(The_Twilight_Zone))?  (I'm looking for an out-of-universe answer regarding the actor, not the in-universe reason given for his character.)

He died in 2015, so that's not the reason.

Comment: Not an answer, but a supposition... the episode "The New Ground" brought back Alexander (Worf's son) in as a repeating character. Georgia Brown was only in this episode for a few scenes, basically telling Worf they're too old to raise the child any more, then we never see either parent again. Bikel's character was not in the script and wouldn't have been needed anyway. Worf's 'mother' was needed only to explain why Alexander was now going to be living with Worf. (not an answer as I have no sources)